# C++ WIN32 Creating An Array of Integers and Booleans in Shared Memory

Tags: c++, arrays, winapi, shared-memory

I'm trying to create an array of int and an array of bools in shared memory. So far I have the following code which runs without errors and 'apparently' creates the memory, however I'm not sure that I can use a LPCTSTR to access the data like an array? Can someone please explain the best way to go about this as I find MSDN quite lacking and painful.

```
void createSharedMemory()
{
    const char slotsName[]="Slots";
    const char flagsName[]="Flags";

    const LONG BufferSize = sizeof(int);
    const LONG Buffers = 10;
    const LONG FlagSize = sizeof(bool); 

    HANDLE hSlots = CreateFileMapping((HANDLE)0xFFFFFFFF, NULL, PAGE_READWRITE, 0, BufferSize * Buffers, SLOTSNAME);
    assert(hSlots != NULL);

    HANDLE hFlags = CreateFileMapping((HANDLE)0xFFFFFFFF, NULL, PAGE_READWRITE, 0, FlagSize * Buffers, flagsName);
    assert(hSlots != NULL);

    std::cout << "Created shared memory!" << std::endl;
}


int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    createSharedMemory();

    HANDLE hSlots;
    LPCTSTR pSlots;

    hSlots = OpenFileMapping(FILE_MAP_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, SLOTSNAME);

    if(hSlots == NULL)
    {
        std::cout << "Could not open slots file mapping object:" << GetLastError() << std::endl;
        getchar();
        return 0;
    }

    pSlots = (LPTSTR) MapViewOfFile(hSlots, FILE_MAP_ALL_ACCESS, 0, 0, 10 * sizeof(int));

    if(pSlots == NULL)
    {
        std::cout << "Could not map view of slots file:" << GetLastError() << std::endl;
        CloseHandle(hSlots);
        getchar();
        return 0;
    }

    std::cout << "Mapped slots correctly!" << std::endl;

    HANDLE hFlags;
    LPCTSTR pFlags;

    hFlags = OpenFileMapping(FILE_MAP_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, FLAGSNAME);

    if(hFlags == NULL)
    {
        std::cout << "Could not open flags file mapping object:" << GetLastError() << std::endl;
        getchar();
        return 0;
    }

    pFlags = (LPTSTR) MapViewOfFile(hFlags, FILE_MAP_ALL_ACCESS, 0, 0, 10 * sizeof(bool));

    if(pFlags == NULL)
    {
        std::cout << "Could not map view of flags file:" << GetLastError() << std::endl;
        CloseHandle(hFlags);
        getchar();
        return 0;
    }

    std::cout << "Mapped flags correctly!" << std::endl;

    //Access the data here

    getchar();

    UnmapViewOfFile(pSlots);
    CloseHandle(hSlots);

    UnmapViewOfFile(pFlags);
    CloseHandle(hFlags);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: why do you create the file mappings relative to a number of `int` and `bool` then cast the returned pointer to `LPTSTR` ?

Comment: Why are you using an explicit cast instead of `INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE`?

Comment: My mistake, I was trying to convert and follow along with an MSDN article.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`MapViewOfFile()` maps the shared memory into your process's address space. From then on (until it is unmapped) you can treat it just like a local chunk of memory that you allocated (or declared on the stack).

The shared memory handle `hSlots` is `10 * sizeof(int)` bytes in size, and if you are really storing ints in this memory then the easiest thing to do is to declare `pSlots` as an `int*`:

```
int* pSlots = reinterpret_cast<int*>( MapViewOfFile(hSlots, FILE_MAP_ALL_ACCESS, 0, 0, 10 * sizeof(int)) );
if (pSlots)
{
    // pSlots can now be used as an array
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        pSlots[i] = i; // etc etc 
    }
}
```